# Accidentally deleted main view in .xib file and now I can't get it back

Tags: iphone, view, xcode4, xib

I accidentally deleted my main iPhone view that was in my .xib file.  This was after I had drawn my entire GUI and buttons.  I was trying to delete a single button, clicked the main view and hit delete, tried to UNDO, but that didn't work.

I put a new view in the .xib file, but my original GUI appears to be gone.

Is there any way to get it back?

Thanks.

Comment: Restore it from your version control system or backup. Other than that, you're out of luck AFAIK.

Comment: If Undo didn't work, might I suggest you head on over to http://bugreporter.apple.com/ and file a bug. You're not the only one who's accidentally removed views we didn't want to, that's precisely what undo is for.

Comment: Try it yourself.  Create a new View Based Application, go to your .xib file that's not your MainWindow.xib, click on the view, hit delete.  It goes away, no undo is possible.  I can't see how to get it back.  Bug?

Comment: If you didn't built your project since you deleted your view, you can go to your project folder and copy the xib file outside the project folder.
Then quit xcode first (because it saves project) and overwrite your xib with the copy and reopen your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Interface Builder. Please file a bug at http://bugreporter.apple.com. In addition to the comments above about using version control, you can choose File->Revert to saved… to go back to the last saved version, if you haven't yet saved/closed the document.

Answer (score 2):

When you delete a file from xcode4, it should ask, "remove the reference" or "remove the file(physically)", but either one, try to find the file in the trash. If you are lucky enough, put back the file then add in to your project again.

Last step, start using version control system. XCode4 has build in version control system, you might give it a try (although I didnt like the XCode4 version, I use "synx", which is free).

Wait wait... back up is very important, so if you dont like version control, you can do simpler task like, zipped it the project folder, and put it in a backup folder before you start add anything new or update anything.